# Перебрать все возможные комбинация списка списков строк

Tags: c#, комбинаторика

У меня есть список списков строк, который представляет таблицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде это условно выглядет так:

```
var content = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "Парень" },
    new List<string> { "Белый", "Смуглый" },
    new List<string> { "Сигарета", "Чупачупс" },
};
```

Список может иметь разное количество столбцов и каждый столбец разное коичество строк. Нужно как-то перебрать все возможные варианты. Результат должен выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде это должно выглядеть как матричный массив строк `string[,]` или список списков строк `List<List<string>>`.

Как можно такое реализовать? Как тут правильно применить рекурсию?

Comment: [Декартово произведение множеств](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) же.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/254877/226545

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1263082/373567

Comment: Если нужно быстрое рабочее решение для больших множеств, то не используйте `List<List<string>>`, используйте вложенные массивы `string[][]`. Матрица `string[,]` здесь хоть и прокатит, но с ней работать будет совсем не удобно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как пример

```
private void GetTable(List<List<string>> content, int index, List<string> state, List<List<string>> ret)
{
    if (index >= content.Count)
    {
        ret.Add(new List<string>(state));
        return;
    }
    foreach (var item in content[index])
    {
        state.Add(item);
        GetTable(content, index + 1, state, ret);
        state.RemoveAt(state.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Проверка

```
var content = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "Парень" },
    new List<string> { "Белый", "Смуглый" },
    new List<string> { "Сигарета", "Чупачупс" },
};

var res = new List<List<string>>();


GetTable(content, 0, new List<string>(), res);

foreach (var row in res)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row));
```

Вывод

```
Парень,Белый,Сигарета
Парень,Белый,Чупачупс
Парень,Смуглый,Сигарета
Парень,Смуглый,Чупачупс
```

Comment: `Stack<T>`, мне кажется, прикольнее бы вписался в реализацию.

Comment: @aepot не хотел его переворачивать в конце, добавило бы сложности в ответ.