# Как перебрать все подмассивы в массиве и сопоставить каждый их элемент с каждым?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

У меня есть массив вида:

```
let main = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'f', 'g']
]
```

Я бы хотел получить все комбинации элементов вложенных массивов, например ad af ag bd bf bg...
Проблема в том, что изначально неизвестно сколько вложено массивов, а так же их длина может различаться. Я ломаю себе голову уже час, может кто-то может мне помочь с этим алгоритмом?

Comment: Поищите `декартово произведение` (cartesian product) - здесь оно точно было.

Comment: что то типа такого? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1322874/179763

Answer (score 0):

Декартово произведение строится с помощью рекурсии.

```js
const cartesian_product = (lists, cb) => {
    if (cb === undefined) {
        const items = [];
        cartesian_product(lists, item => items.push(item.slice()));
        return items;
    }

    let item = new Array(lists.length);
    const gen = i => {
        if (i === lists.length) {
            cb(item);
            return;
        }
        for (let v of lists[i]) {
            item[i] = v;
            gen(i + 1);
        }
    };
    gen(0);
};

const main = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'f', 'g']
];

cartesian_product(main, console.log);
console.log(cartesian_product(main));
```